Underwater intense movie
I'm trying to find a movie,  but I don't remember much about it.
Color movie, I cannot precise the year but I would say definitely after 2000.
English Language
All I know is that it has a lot of underwater scenes, it's very intense, there's a scene of a guy killing other by drowning him, because he cannot keep up due to injury, and its a very intense scene as the guy that dies, only has his hand out of water and desperately tries to fight back.
And in the last scene, the main char, has low oxygen, no light, and he pulls out a necklace that someone gave to him, that emits some light, and allows him to successfully find the way out.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
